# Higher power of logarithms connected to Robin and Nicolas inequalities

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I know from Dusart papers and other similar papers that,  $ c_1 + \ln \theta(x) \leq \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{\ln p}{p} $ and that $c_0+ \ln \ln \theta(x) \leq \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} $ are equivalent to R.H. ($c_0,c_1$ are known and explicit values but are not important to the question here)

Recently I came across a formula that relates $\theta(x)$ to summations like $ \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{\ln^2 p}{p}$ and $ \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{\ln^3 p}{p}$, so my question is : is the R.H. equivalent to $ c_2 + \frac{\ln^2 \theta(x)}{2} \leq  \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{\ln^2 p}{p}$  ??

If the above is true, then can we always build an inequality for a polynomial in respect to $\ln p$ such as $ \ln^3 p- 3 \ln^3 p +7 \ln p -11$  in the summation that is equivalent to R.H. ?

A ref to published paper is good answer too.

Note : for constant polynomial or linear polynomial with respect to $\ln p$ the answer is true, simply be applying robin's inequality multiplied with constant.

Thanks.

Edit : [The question on Math OverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374385/higher-powers-of-logarithms-in-summations-over-primes-connected-to-r-h)

Comment: What do you get from $ \sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{\ln p}{p}=\log x + a+ O(x^{\sigma-1+\epsilon})$ iff $\zeta(s)$ has no zero for $\Re(s) > \sigma$, and $\sum \limits_{p \leq x} \ln p=x+ O(x^{\sigma+\epsilon})$ iff $\zeta(s)$ has no zero for $\Re(s) > \sigma$.

Comment: @reuns but in my case the $p$ in the denominator remains fixed it's the power of the logarithm that changes !! so I am not sure in my case if it's equivalent to R.H.?